# confirmation dialog when addressing a function

Tags: php, html

I have a function specified in html. This function is called through onclick on a table cell. Normally I would also use onclick to create a confirmation dialog to ask if the person is sure to delete the row of data in this case.
I'm wondering if there is any way to go about this and still have the confirmation box pop up to link to the function. I'm pretty much out of ideas.
little piece of code to show what I mean with addressing my function.

```
echo "<td class='option' onclick=\"deleteEvent($eventID)\">Delete</td>";
```

Comment: That onclick handler will try to execute a javascript function called deleteEvent. In this function you can do whatever you want, just ask if they're sure, and if so - send an ajax request to some php script that deletes it.

Comment: Fixed typos and grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this via the [window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) API.

Example:

```
if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) { 
  //Do the Delete Operation
}
```